# How do I insert a foreign key automatically without having to look it up myself?

Tags: sql, foreign-keys

I have three tables; customers, orders, products.

I want to insert which customer ordered which product into the orders table. So far I can only do this by manually looking at the customer_id and the product_id then using INSERT INTO orders(customer_id, product_id) VALUES ("3", "5); which will link customer number 3 to product number 5.

This works and I can SELECT out the data and it is fine. But I don't want to have to look at the numbers to enter the data. I just want to type the NAME of the customer and the NAME of the product and let SQL find and insert the correct keys for me. Surely this must be easy but I just can't figure it out.

Thanks all in advance.

Comment: that has nothing to do with sql. that's a client-side thing to "automate" those lookups. it's not an sql server's job to read your mind, it just does what you tell it to, and ONLY what you tell it to.

Comment: Are you doing manual inserts?

Comment: Create a view with an `instead of` trigger

Answer (score -2):

Something like the following can help?

INSERT INTO orders(customer_id, product_id)

SELECT customer_id from customers where name = 'name1

UNION

SELECT product_id from products where name = 'name2'

Of course, the names should be unique.